# Scanning for Bluetooth Devices in Qt

Tags: android, c++, qt, sockets, bluetooth

Here is my code: I have a class called `bluetoothCommunication` in which I need to place some methods for exchanging data via bluetooth.

```
 bluetoothCommunication::bluetoothCommunication()
{
    QBluetoothLocalDevice localDevice;
    QString localDeviceName;
    //Check if Bluetooth is available on this device
    if(localDevice.isValid()){
        //Turn Bluetooth on
        localDevice.powerOn();
        //Read local device name
        localDeviceName = localDevice.name();
        //Make it visible to others
        localDevice.setHostMode(QBluetoothLocalDevice::HostDiscoverable);
        //Get connected devices
        QList<QBluetoothAddress> remotes;
        remotes = localDevice.connectedDevices();
    }
}

void bluetoothCommunication::startDeviceDiscovery()
    {
    qDebug() << "Bluetooth discovery started";

    //Create a discovery agent and connect to its signals
    QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent* discoveryAgent = new QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent();
    QObject::connect(discoveryAgent, SIGNAL(deviceDiscovered(QBluetoothDeviceInfo*)), &this, SLOT(deviceDiscovered(QBluetoothDeviceInfo*))); //HERE I HAVE AN ERROR //DON'T KNOW WHERE AND WHY
    //Start a discovery
    discoveryAgent -> start();
}
```

I have tried to modify the official example from qt documentation (which is the following), that gives me error during compiling if I copy and paste it:

```
    void MyClass::startDeviceDiscovery()
{
// Create a discovery agent and connect to its signals
QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent *discoveryAgent = new QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent(this);
connect(discoveryAgent, SIGNAL(deviceDiscovered(QBluetoothDeviceInfo)),
        this, SLOT(deviceDiscovered(QBluetoothDeviceInfo)));

// Start a discovery
discoveryAgent->start();

//...
}
```

However my attempt to fix it still doesn't work. With error message:

> In member function `void
>   bluetoothCommunication::startDeviceDiscovery()`: lvalue required as
>   unary  `&` operand

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143526/discussion-on-question-by-elena-scanning-for-bluetooth-devices-in-qt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, following the [sample documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbluetoothdevicediscoveryagent.html) I managed to produce a small sample of your code compiling.

Start notes:

- You need QtCreator 5.2 or higher to compile the QBluetooth libraries.
- In the .pro file add Qt += bluetooth
- Use the sample provided by Qt documentation
- In the header file include all libraries and add the methods definitions.

**bluetoothSample.pro**

```
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets bluetooth

TARGET = bluetoothSample
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000 

SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

**mainWindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent>
#include <QBluetoothDeviceInfo>

namespace Ui {
  class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

private:
  Ui::MainWindow *ui;
  void startDeviceDiscovery();

private slots:
  void deviceDiscovered(const QBluetoothDeviceInfo &device);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>

void MainWindow::startDeviceDiscovery()
{
  // Create a discovery agent and connect to its signals
  QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent *discoveryAgent = new QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent(this);
  connect(discoveryAgent, SIGNAL(deviceDiscovered(QBluetoothDeviceInfo)),
        this, SLOT(deviceDiscovered(QBluetoothDeviceInfo)));

  // Start a discovery
  discoveryAgent->start();

  //...
}

// In your local slot, read information about the found devices
void MainWindow::deviceDiscovered(const QBluetoothDeviceInfo &device)
{
  qDebug() << "Found new device:" << device.name() << '(' << device.address().toString() << ')';
}
```

Comment: I verified on my own Qt Creator. Did you see my start notes? 
Qt creator has to be version 5.2 or higher and in the .pro file you have to add Qt += bluetooth.

Comment: Yes I did, with no results.

Answer (score 1):

I have scanning problem with standart examples.
I solved problem, remove uuid filtr:

//m_discoveryAgent->setUuidFilter(uuid);
devices found.